# Swift: does capturing a function parameter, within a closure, hold it strongly?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

**Capturing a function parameter within a closure**

```
func someFunction(tableView: UITableView) -> (() -> ()) {

    return { [weak self] in

        self?.someOtherFunction() {
            tableView.performTask()
        }

    }

}
```

If so, what is the syntax for ensuring the tableView parameter is weak, in the above example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closure capture parameters strongly by default. In most common cases in closure you accessing to properties declared in `self`, without capturing other references, so making `self` weak is enough. In your case you need expand closure capture list and include `tableView` to it:

```
func someFunction(tableView: UITableView) -> (() -> ()) {
    return { [weak self, weak tableView] in
        self?.someOtherFunction() {
            tableView?.performTask()
        }
    }
}
```

You may read more about capture lists in [ARC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) documentation:

> You resolve a strong reference cycle between a closure and a class
>   instance by defining a capture list as part of the closure’s
>   definition. A capture list defines the rules to use when capturing
>   **one or more reference types within the closure’s body**. As with strong reference cycles between two class instances, you declare each
>   captured reference to be a weak or unowned reference rather than a
>   strong reference.